# Move a 1 dimensional array into a 2 dimensional

Tags: java, arrays

I have a 1 dimensional array that contains data like:

```
Dog, Cat, Cow, 3213
Meat, Fred, John, 3123
Apples, Fries, Lollies, 1231
```

And I want to turn it into a 2 dimensional array, split at the comma.

Comment: Your question only contains requirements - it is not showing any efforts from your side to solve this problem yourself. Please add your attempts to this questions - as this site is not a free "we do your (home)work" service. Beyond that: please turn to the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to learn how/what to ask here. Thanks

Comment: How many elements are in this array?